# Ring homomorphisms form an abelian group

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, abelian-groups

Let ${\rm Hom}(\mathbb{Z}_n,\mathbb{Z}_m)$ be the set of all ring homomorphisms. I am not assuming $f(1) = 1$. My question is,

> Is it possible to give an abelian group structure in this set?

I know this is true for group homomorphism as the co-domain is an abelian group. But, in the case of ring homomorphisms, $f+g$ need not satisfy the ring homomorphism conditions. What is the natural operation that makes ${\rm Hom}(\mathbb{Z}_n,\mathbb{Z}_m)$ into an abelian group?

I am trying to prove the following equation on pg no. 259 in this paper: https://fada.birzeit.edu/bitstream/20.500.11889/4045/1/homo-monthly.pdf

[image]

Kindly share your thoughts. Thank you.

Comment: The paper is just wrong when it says they are abelian groups.

Comment: I am also thought so. Thanks. At least  as a set the cardinalitities of LHS and RHS are equal?

Answer (score -2):

To give a (not necessarily unital) ring homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}_n$ to $\mathbb{Z}_m$ is the same as giving an idempotent in $\mathbb{Z}_m$ whose order divides $n$. Now, it is well known that the idempotents in any unital commutative ring form a Boolean ring, with the same multiplication and the "sum" of $e$ and $f$ being $e+f-2ef$. Also, it is easily seen that if $e$ and $f$ have order diving $n$, then so does $e+f-2ef$. Finally, with this addition, the identity element is still zero and every element is its own inverse. Hence, there is an isomorphic abelian group structure on the set of ring homomorphisms from $\mathbb{Z}_n$ to $\mathbb{Z}_m$ with $(f +' g)(k)=k[f(1)+g(1)-2f(1)g(1)]$ (using the prime mark to avoid confusion with the pointwise sum).

Comment: This seems rather irrelevant to the asker's motivation, though, which is just about an erroneous line in a paper.

Comment: It's also a finite set of some cardinality $N$ and it's thus in bijection with the ring $\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z}$. This is not saying much... Every set is in bijection with some ring.